# Custom jQuery extension won't work with Drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal, this

Trying to tie a custom jQuery extension into Drupal 7 I'm running into a problem with the "this" object within my script.

My code is wrapped properly to support no conflict and works fine outside of drupal, but identical code on a drupal page fails.

I added console.log(this) to the top of my extension and found that outside drupal, I get a proper jQuery object with the matching node within. Inside drupal I get just the matching element.

Drupal 7 has jQuery 1.4.4 and my code runs fine in jQuery 1.4.2 and 1.6.2.

What can I do about this?

Comment: I downloaded the jQuery Update module to see if it was the particular jQuery version and it still has the same issue with jQuery 1.5.2.

Comment: I also added console.log(jQuery('#Navigation')); to see what I get from that and it has the same problem: it's returning a DOMElement rather than a jQuery object when run on a drupal page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to give you a great answer. I ran into a similar (sounding) problem a while back and used this technique to wrap inline JQuery on a Drupal 7 site, and this solved my problem :

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // Insert your code here.

    });
})(jQuery);
```

The issue is that Drupal 7 is strict on the namespace and doesn't allow the default `$` as a function alias like you could do in Drupal 6.

Comment: Indirectly this solved my problem... the all important one line that calls my extension wasn't wrapped in a $(document).ready call.

I'm not entirely sure why the "this" object had strange behavior but otherwise seemed to work... but I just needed my code to wait for the page to settle.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique in Drupal is to wrap the jQuery inside this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Insert code here.
});
```